# Find second largest number from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array `a = [3,6,774,24,56,2,64,56,34]`.  I need to find the second largest number in a single iteration using Ruby. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simple:

```
array.sort[-2]
```

And you're done :)

Comment: That's not a single iteration :)

Comment: The values in the array are dynamically filled. So we are not aware about the values in the array. In that case, how will we iterate and find the 2nd largest value

Comment: If you don't know what kind of object is in there and it can not be sorted, there is no way to know what is the largest value. Your object has to define some kind of order and the best solution for this is to implement the **<=>** method and include the **Comparable** module.

Comment: I don't understand that the array "is dynamically filled". This is not the most space-efficient solution, but unless the OP says that the input array is enormous and the intermediate array creation must be avoided at all cost, it's the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

This works, but am not sure for the "single iteration"

`a.max(2)[1]`

Answer (score 2):

`sort` is probably overkill here, especially for really large arrays. Don't quite understand "single iteration", one line you mean?

```
a = [3,6,774,24,56,2,64,56,34]
b = a.shift(2).sort
c = 
  a.inject(b) do |(m2, m), e| 
    case
    when e > m
      [m, e]
    when e > m2
      [e, m]
    else
      [m2, m]
    end
  end
c.first #=> 64
```

Comment: I guess that the OP meant O(n).

Comment: I am just learning ruby. So what values does this m2, m and e contains.?? I understand from the tutorials that the e would contain the values of each element of the array.. but (m2,m) is little confusing..

Comment: It is called destructuring, if you pass `[a, b], c` to a block `do |(x, y), z| ... end` then `a -> x, b -> y, c -> z`. `b` in my code is a two element array like `[a, b]` here (and I return two element array as a result of the block too, so it will go to memo on the next step).

Comment: this is indeed O(n), but Victor, what would be really interesting is a generic "take the Nth largest"-abstraction :-)

Comment: @tokland I believe generic is `sort`, but I would not use `sort` to find max value (or second max value) just because it's generic.

Comment: @Victor: I've added an answer with the idea I had in mind (without sort, at least without sorting the whole array)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, this method gets the Nth greatest value in a enumerable (you'd use a bisect module to make the insertion into `acc` more efficient). As pointed out by @Victor, you would only use it when the length of the array is much bigger than n, othersize a simple `array.sort[-n]` is faster.

```
module Enumerable
  def max_nth(n)
    inject([]) do |acc, x|
      (acc + [x]).sort[[acc.size-(n-1), 0].max..-1]
    end.first
  end
end

p [1, 5, 2, 32, 2, 41, 15, 55].max_nth(2) #=> 41
```

Comment: I had this idea too, but there is a wrinkle here. When n << array size it may work well, but in other cases `sort` does it better. So when you say "generic" it is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Victor. Indeed, that's better suited for n << array_size. But I guess than in practical situations that's the case. Anyway, it's less code than using conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

For me,

```sh
a = [3,6,774,24,56,2,64,56,34]

a.uniq # create a new array with the only unique value

a.sort[-2] # find the second greatest value
```

Answer (score 0):

It works too:

```html
arr.sort.reverse[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:
`data_array5 = [45,65632,232,34345,343,23,23,56]`
`puts data_array5.sort[data_array5.length()-2]`

This is generic you replace 2 with any n number to get nth maxmium

Answer (score -1):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
puts array.max(2).last
```

Comment: `[1].max(2).last` gives you `1`